# LINQ Lazy Inner Join

Tags: c#, linq

Is there a way to make use of LINQ API to (inner) join collections in a lazy fashion? I face a situation where I need to correlate multiple CSVs in cascade and would like to avoid unnecessary parsing operations if "upstream" CSVs turn out to be empty:

```
ReadCsvRows(fileA).Join(
    ReadCsvRows(fileB), // why to parse B if A is empty?!
    ...
).Join(
    ReadCsvRows(fileC),
    ...
).Join(...)
```

Note that `ReadCsvRows` method lies behind an interface, only requirement of which is that method has to return `IEnumerable` (as depicted [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/EMDNO8)). To keep things "streamy", I could get around the problem by introducing custom extension method

```
public static IEnumerable<TResult> Join<TOuter, TInner, TKey, TResult>(
    this IEnumerable<TOuter> outer, 
    Func<IEnumerable<TInner>> innerFunc, 
    Func<TOuter, TKey> outerKeySelector, 
    Func<TInner, TKey> innerKeySelector, 
    Func<TOuter, TInner, TResult> resultSelector) =>
        !outer.Any() ?
        Array.Empty<TResult>() :
        outer.Join(
            innerFunc(),
            outerKeySelector,
            innerKeySelector,
            resultSelector
        );
```

but was wondering what options do I have with vanilla LINQ API.

Comment: This depends on how `ReadCsvRows` is implemented, and its return type (IEnumerable vs List). https://dotnetfiddle.net/dMDcyf Can you post a [mre]?

Comment: Looks like you do not need own `Join` implementation. You have to correctly write  `ReadCsvRows` function. How it looks like by the way?

Comment: Thanks for (correctly) pointing out that implementation of CSV parsing logic needs to be considered. I'll update question accordingly.

Comment: Using one big chained expression is seldom a good idea. If you want to check the data before joining, *don't* call `ReadCsvRows` in the LINQ query. Do it in advance. You won't convert your CSV files to databases by using LINQ. The data will be loaded in memory anyway, iterated and joined in a brute force fashion, without using any indexes. If you want to speed things up, use a Dictionary for one of the files based on the common key and use it to look up values while iterating the other key. If you want to use LINQ in this case you'll only need a `Select` over the second file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need own `Join` implementation. Standard `System.Linq` implementation do not enumerate `inner` sequence if `outer` has no records.

So, check your `ReadCsvRows` implementation. If you use `yield return` in it's body, no unwanted reads will appear.

Schematically:

```cs
public static IEnumerable<Row> ReadCsvRows(string fileName)
{
   using var reader = new CsvReader(fileName);
   while (reader.ReadNext())
   {
      yield return reader.CurrentRow;
   }
}
```

In this case even `new CsvReader(fileName)` will be NOT called if first sequence has no rows.

Answer (score 0):

If I were you, I would split ReadCsvRows(fileB) and ReadCsvRows(fileC) into two seperate variables. And add an "If" condition to determine if "ReadCSVRows(fileB)" should be executed or not.

Something like this:

```
List<FileATypeA> fileAData = ReadCsvRows(fileA);
List<FileATypeB> fileBData = new List<FileATypeB>();
List<FileATypeC> fileCData =  new List<FileTypeC>();

if(fileAData.Count() > 0)
    fileBData = ReadCsvRows(fileB);
if(fileBData.Count() > 0)
    fileCData = ReadCsvRows(fileC);

List<FinalType> final = from a in fileAData
                        join b in fileBData
                             on a.Key = b.Key
                        join c in fileCData
                             on b.Key = c.Key
```

See if this helps

Comment: I haven't compiled it, but it should be something similar to that